# Best education for non-heir children

Tags: crusader-kings-3

I was wondering what education focus I should choose for children that will not be my heir. What are pros and cons? As far as I understand, their education focus will later determine what skill tree they will put points in and thus what actions they have available? Does it have impact on their general behavior, like martial education likes to conquer more and intrigue education likes to scheme more? What do you pick in your games?

Comment: Are you talking about courtiers who won't matter, or about your direct descendants (who might end up becoming a problem for your heir later)?

Answer (score 4):

It depends what your plans for them are. Will they be a future vassal, or an independent ruler? Are they heading towards friendship or rivalry with the player heir.

In general, you don't want rivals or vassals with high **intrigue** (except for your spymaster).

Vassals with high **martial** are good (they'll be your knights) but not independent rulers (they'll be harder to beat).

Vassals with high **stewardship** are good (you'll get more tax). It doesn't affect rivals much - they'll develop faster but once you take their lands that development becomes yours.

High **learning** is generally good. They make good priests, physicians, and antiquarians. They also advance the discoveries of their culture (which will likely be the same as yours) when independent.

High **diplomacy** doesn't have much direct effect. People will like them more, so their own vassals will be less likely to rebel against them. You're more likely to lose events against them when your own lifestyle is Diplomatic.